# Python: Importing file from another location

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-import

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, I've tried a bunch of the methods listed in other questions, so I'm going to re-ask in case I'm missing something.

I have the following structure:

```
|-bin/
  -file.py
|-unittests/
  -__init__.py
  |-test_bin/
    -__init__.py
    -test_file.py
```

I've tried the following inside `test_file.py` to no avail:

1) `Import Error: No module named bin.file`

```
from bin.file import *
```

2) `Import Error: No module named bin.file`

```
import sys
from os import path
sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))
from bin.file import *
```

3) `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

```
from ...bin.file import *
```

The command I'm using is `python test_file.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your import to work you need to be at the root of your project.

However, you can add a setup.py file at the root of your package which will allow you to import your functons from anywhere (see below):

Setup.py :

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='test',
    version='0.1',
    packages=['bin']
)
```

and then you run the following shell command at the root of your project:

```
python setup.py develop
```

[image]

With these steps you should be able to import your file as wanted.

Note that the test.eff-info folder is automatically created.

I hope it helps

Comment: Note that python `setup.py install` works too. The difference is in the fact that the modifications in your notification are automatically applied or not.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to run `python setup.py develop --user`, now I'm hitting another problem though, as `file.py` is no longer able to import its modules after being imported into `test_file.py`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your second problem. Have you tried `from bin.file import [name_of_the_function]`

Comment: Nevermind - it's a complete unrelated problem to how the code is structured. Your solution helped me with the question of importing a module.

Answer (score 0):

Python imports are a bit weird. First, to fix your problem- add an empty file called `__init__.py` to your bin directory. Now to explain why-

Python builds up a search path. It uses all directories in the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus `site-packages` for your virtualenv or your base interpreter. Generally, running `python` will also add the current working directory to PYTHONPATH.

So any `.py` file in one of those directories can be imported. But for modules, it doesn't look at EVERY directory. Instead, it only counts directories that contain that magic `__init__.py` file. So you would have seen `bin.py` there.. but not `bin/bin.py`, until you add the `__init__.py` file.

(this goes for nested directories all the way down).

Looking at your question, this may still be an issue- if you're running your command from the bottom directory where test_file is, your root directory isn't on the search path to see `bin` anyway. So you would have to do `PYTHONPATH=../..:$PYTHONPATH python test_file.py` or run the command from the root `python unittests/test_bin/test_file.py`

Comment: from `python` 3.3+ `__init__.py` is not necessary.

Comment: That's interesting- Guess I had gotten so used to debugging that issue in 2.7 I didn't realize they stopped happening!

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below at the beginning of the `test_file.py`It will get current dir of your current file, then find the sub dir which is `unittests` and finally it will reach parent dir `bin`.

Also, it's good to change the name of file => `file.py` to another name to avoid conflicts.

Try the code below and let me know.

```
import os,sys,inspect
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
unittests_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
bin_dir = os.path.dirname(unittests_dir)
sys.path.insert(0, bin_dir)

import file
```